# Posix shell script - Save multi line command output to variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, posix

When I save a command output which contains several lines to a variable directly into my terminal, I have the following results :

```
$ dirs=$(ls -1d /mnt/*/)
$ echo $dirs
/mnt/ext4/ /mnt/local/ /mnt/remote/ /mnt/test/
$ echo "$dirs"
/mnt/ext4/
/mnt/local/
/mnt/remote/
/mnt/test/
```

However when using it from a posix shell script the result is different.
Here is the script

```
#!/bin/sh

dirs=$(ls -1d $1)
echo "inline"
echo $dirs
echo "multiline"
echo "$dirs"
```

And here is the script output

```
$ ./test.sh /mnt/*/
inline
/mnt/ext4/
multiline
/mnt/ext4/
```

This happens even if I use bash instead of sh.

Does anyone know how I could save the output of `ls -1d /mnt/*/` into a variable keeping the full output ? 
I would like to parse each of the four directory paths inside a for loop.

Comment: The important question here is: what are you going to do with those filenames the script receives as arguments? I'm about 95 % sure that you don't actually want to concatenate them to a single string, but would be better off just looping over the arguments as given.

Comment: Basically it's for separate the name of the directory and the path itself to create a single variable containing something like ` -x <name1> <path1> -x <name2> <path2> -x <name3> <path3> ...`. It's done now ;) The answer was so obvious I didn't realize immediately that /mnt/*/ was expanded as separate arguments....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ ./test.sh /mnt/*/
```

The glob here expands to the directory names as separate arguments, same as if you wrote them out manually on the command line:

```
$ ./test.sh /mnt/ext4/ /mnt/local/ /mnt/remote/ /mnt/test/
```

However, in the script itself, you refer to only the first argument, `$1`:

```
dirs=$(ls -1d $1)
```

If you want to refer to all the arguments, use `"$@"` (with the quotes).

However, all you're doing with the directory names here is to run `ls` on them, which just prints the same names out (though on separate lines). So, if you just want the list of the arguments as a string, you don't need to run the `ls` command at all, just assign `dirs="$@"`.

Nevertheless, in most, if not all cases it's better to just keep the list of file names in the positional parameters, and loop over them with

```
for f in "$@"; do ...
```

or

```
for f
do ...
```

Note that file names might contain white space, and when you concatenate the names to a single string, you lose the meaning of the whitespace within the names. `foo bar doo` might be three files, or the two files `foo bar` and `doo`.